# Rails 3: Where to put a Rails.cache.fetch "cache warmer" call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, low-level

Assume you want to do some low level caching in Rails (with memcached, for example) and that you'd like to have just 1 call somewhere in your app, like...

```
Rails.cache.fetch('books', expires_in: 1.day) do
  Book.offset(offset)
      .limit(limit)
      .select('title, author, number_of_pages')
      .all
end
```

...to warm up your cache when you boot your app, so you can just use a simple call like...

```
Rails.cache.read('books')
```

...*anywhere* and multiple times throughout your app (in views, controllers, helpers...) to access this "books" collection.

Where should one put the initial "fetch" call to make it work?

Comment: Why do this on app boot? If your cache expires in 1.day, wouldn't you rather have this run once a day? I'd wrap it in a rake task and run it with `cron`.

Comment: @spike - Suppose the value of :expires_in could also be much longer. (And I thought doing it on app boot because I'd use the shorter "Rails.cache.read" everywhere else.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your comment I want to clear up a couple of things.

You should always be using `fetch` if you require a result to come back. Wrap the call in a class method inside `Book` for easy access:

```
class Book
  def self.cached_books 
    Rails.cache.fetch < ... > 
  end
end
```

You can have a different method forcing the cache to be recreated:

```
def self.write_book_cache
     Rails.cache.write < ... > 
   end
end
```

Then in your initializer, or in a rake task, you can just do:

```
Book.write_book_cache
```

This seems more maintainable to me, while keeping the succinct call to the cache in the rest of your code.

Comment: Is it a MUST to always be using "fetch"? I mean, even if you know you've already filled the cache somehow, like on app boot?

Comment: If memcached runs out of space it will drop older keys. You shouldn't assume that your cache *certainly* exists just because you put something there.

Comment: (PS: If I'm not mistaken, "Book.write_book_cache" would go in a config.after_initialize do ... end block in application.rb, so you have the models loaded, unlike in an initializer.)

Comment: To improve further: the 2 methods above can become 1 by using the first one and simply setting force: true

Comment: That was my first thought, but I actually think two methods is clearer than one generic `cached_books` that takes an argument which makes it destructive.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought would be to put it in an initializer - probably one specifically for the purpose (`/config/initializers/init_cache.rb`, or something similar).

It should be executed automatically (by virtue of being in the initializers folder) when the app starts up.

Comment: The problem with this solution would be that the models must be loaded before that cache can be filled.